# Show that for $t\in\mathbb{R}$ it is $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(G(x+t)-G(x))\, dx=t$ (distribution function)

Tags: measure-theory, probability-distributions

> > Let $G$ be the distribution function of a probability measure on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$. Show that for $t\in\mathbb{R}$ it is
> >     $$
> > \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(G(x+t)-G(x))\, dx=t.
> > $$

Let $G$ be the distribution function of the probability measure, which I call $P$. Then it is $G(x)=P((-\infty,x])$. So it is
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(G(x+t)-G(x))\, dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(P((-\infty,x+t])-P((-\infty,x))\, dx.
$$
I do not know how to continue. Maybe with
$$
P((-\infty,x+t])=\int_{(-\infty,x+t]}dP,~~~~~P((-\infty,x])=\int_{(-\infty,x]}\, dP,
$$
maybe with something completely different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By properties of $P$ we have that
$$
G(x+t)-G(x)=P((x,x+t])=\int_{\mathbb R}\mathbf{1}_{(x,x+t]}(y)\, P(\mathrm dy)
$$
and hence
$$
\int_{\mathbb R}[G(x+t)-G(x)]\,\mathrm dx=\int_{\mathbb R}\int_{\mathbb R}\mathbf{1}_{(x,x+t]}(y)\, P(\mathrm dy)\,\mathrm dx.\tag{1}
$$
Now, $\mathbf{1}_{(x,x+t]}(y)=1$ if and only if $\mathbf{1}_{[y-t,y)}(x)=1$, and so by Tonelli's theorem $(1)$ becomes
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbf{1}_{[y-t,y)}(x)\,\mathrm dx\,P(\mathrm dy)=t.
$$

Comment: One question: We had Tonelli resp. Fubini for two measures. Here one mesaure is $P$, but what's the other?

Comment: The other is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: $dx$ means Riemann-integral... Why is the Riemann-integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}}(G(x+t)-G(x))\, dx$ identical with the Lebesgue-integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}}(G(x+t)-G(x))\, d\lambda(dx)$ here? Is $\lvert G(x+t)-G(x)\rvert$ improper Riemann-integrable?

Comment: In general if $f$ is measurable and Riemann-integrable, then $f$ is Lebesgue-integrable and $\int_a^b f(x)\,\mathrm dx=\int_a^b f(x)\,\lambda(\mathrm dx)$. Also, any bounded function with at most countably many discontinuities is Riemann-integrable (which is true for $G$, why?).

Comment: I know it that way: If a function is Lebesgue-integrable (relating to the Lebesgue-measure) and has at most countably many points of noncontinuity, then from Lebesgue-integrability it follows Riemann-integrability. So I ask myself if G is Lebesgue integrable relating to $\lambda$? (Because of the continuity from right it has at most countably many points where it is not continious.)

Comment: I just showed that $x\mapsto G(x+t)-G(x)$ is Lebesgue-integrable in my answer, didn't I? Just replace the $\mathrm dx$'s by $\lambda(\mathrm dx)$.

Comment: In order to use Fubini, isn't it necessary, to show that the function in the integrand is measurable?

Comment: @math12: Yes, which should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: I have to show, that $1_{(x,x+t]}\colon\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}, (x,y)\mapsto 1_{(x,x+t]}(y)$ is measurable?

Comment: @math12: Yes.${}$